# Jabref Help "Unable to open link"

Tags: jabref

I am having a BibTeX entry in JabRef and the corresponding .bib-file is stored in a Dropbox folder. It links to .pdf-files on two different machines, that means two external links in Tab->General->File. However, it could only open the first link, and when changing the machine, it will be annoying to change the link order. Any idea to solve that?

Comment: I understand that you found a solution. Would be nice if you answered your own question, so that other people finding this question can easily see how you solved it.

Comment: Sorry, but this is really not about TeX _per se_

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way: put your file next to your .bib in the Dropbox folder and do a relative reference.

Second possible way: Put the file on both machines in a folder with exactly the same directory. Difficult for cross-platform work.

Most flexible but hacky way: Use the `File` field for one file and the `Url` field for the other.
This would look like this:

```
@BOOK{Test2013,
  author = {Test},
  title = {Test},
  year = {2013},
  url = {file:///D:/Documents%20and%20Settings/test.pdf},
  file = {:C\:\\Documents and Settings\\test.pdf:PDF},
  owner = {Me},
  timestamp = {2013.11.22}
}
```

The url of your file can be addressed as described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/file-uris-in-windows).

Comment: I have to put reference pdf file locally for limited spaces in dropbox. And I have got a better solution. Setting the file directory in database properties in file menu and on different PCs, directories could be different. So one synchronized jabref bib file in dropbox can reach different pdf file subjected to the set local directory.